# Rhino Mocks: How can I mock out a method that transforms its input?

Tags: c#, .net, rhino-mocks

I have a Data Access Object TransactionDao.  When you call TransactionDao.Save(transaction) I would like for it to setting a transaction.IsSaved=true flag (this is a simplification the actual thing I'm trying to do is not quite so banal).  So when mocking my TransactionDao with RhinoMocks how can I indicate that it should transform its input?

Ideally I would like to write something like this:

```
Expect.Call(delegate {dao.Save(transaction);}).Override(x => x.IsSaved=true);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

---

Though I got a hint how to do it from the answer specified below the actual type signature is off, you have to do something like this:
Because of what Mark Ingram posted, seems like the best answer, though nobody's explicitly said it, is to do this:

```
public delegate void FakeSave(Transaction t);
...
Expect.Call(delegate {dao.Save(t); }).Do( new FakeSave(delegate(Transaction t2) { t.IsSaved = true; }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gorge,

The simplest solution, which I found, applied to your question  is the following:

```
Expect.Call(() => dao.Save(transaction))
    .Do(new Action<Transaction>(x => x.IsSaved = true));
```

So you don't need to create a special delegate or anything else. Just use Action which is in standard .NET 3.5 libraries.

Hope this help.
Frantisek

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the Do callback:

```
Expect.Call(delegate {dao.Save(transaction);})
    .Do(x => x.IsSaved = true);
```

Comment: Thank you, though the syntax is not exactly correct, its giving me a cannot convert lambda to delegate error, once I figure out the exact syntax I'll post it and mark your answer.

Comment: George, since the Expect.Call(...).Do answer was correct (only syntax error), I would appreciate a 1 up vote for my answer.

Thanks friend.

Answer (score -1):

you should mock the transaction and make it return true fo IsSaved, if you can mock the transaction of course.

```
ITransaction transaction = _Mocker.dynamicMock<ITransaction>;
Expect.Call(transaction.IsSaved).IgnoreArguments.Return(true);
_mocker.ReplayAll();
dao.Save(transaction);
```

Comment: Like I said, this is a simplification of what I'm doing, there are other changes that take place in the parameter and other flags that could be set.  I need to know how to work with a byreference parameter basically